# Overlay a ListDensityPlot with ListContourPlot

Tags: plotting, overlay

I have a ListCountourPlot and a ListDensityPlot, generated by the code lines below. Now, I would like to superimpose them somehow, so that I can see the two plots on top of each other, much like I would do with a Show[{plot1,plot2}], if plot1 and plot2 were simple Plots. I tried Overlay but this doesn't do the job either...

```
plot1 = ListContourPlot[Reverse[Transpose[negflux1new], 2], 
PlotRange -> {Full, Full, {0.01, 1}}, ClippingStyle -> Darker[White, 0.01], 
ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"Angle of incidence [rad]", "Wave frequency  \[Omega] [1/s]"}, PlotRange -> Full, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
BaseStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.3]]]

plot2 =  ListDensityPlot[{Reverse[kLImrev[[;; , ;; , 1]], 2], ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
     ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
     Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Angle of incidence [rad]", 
       "Wave frequency  \[Omega] [1/s]"}, PlotRange -> Full, 
     PlotLabel -> "Incident L, Im(k1) first mode", 
     PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

These commands produce these pictures and I'd just like to have this little stripe of the first on top of the second. Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's hard to answer the question without the data, but it looks like changing `Darker[White, 0.01]` to `Opacity[0]` then calling `Show[plot2, plot1]` might do the trick.

Comment: Cheers, that solved my issue! For future reference, all my data had dimensions (501,91) and each point had value between 0 and 1.